# Renaming files with long filenames in windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a list of file names : old and new

sample is given below:

Old Name:

```
Fiscal Policy and Stimulus Crash Course Economics #3.mp3
```

New Name:

```
03_Fiscal Policy and Stimulus Crash Course Economics.mp3
```

How do I rename the files using Windows rename command?

```
ren oldfilename newfilename
```

is not working even after using the file names within double quotes.

The line below was put in a batch file:

```
RENAME "Fiscal Policy and Stimulus Crash Course Economics #3.mp3" "03_Fiscal Policy and Stimulus Crash Course Economics.mp3"
```

The batch file was run at the Windows Command Prompt and the response was "The syntax of the command is not correct."

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have updated what I did. Maybe I did something wrong. Please let me know. Windows 10 Home edition. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me too. Just out of curiosity: what's the name of the batch file? Could it be rename.bat?

Comment: Yes. It is rename. bat

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: Tried renaming the file to rename1.bat. The error message has now changed. Now it shows "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: In retrospect @Will is probably right that this is a question more suitable for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)

Comment: The `rename` command line is correct, but perhaps your working directory is not the source directory; try to specify the full path to the source file...

Comment: Those filenames aren't long enough to cause complications, unless perhaps the full path to the directory is very long.  More likely there's just a typo in the file name specified in the command, or a hidden character in the actual filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to create a batch file with the name of an internal command (a command integrated in cmd - full list can be found [here](https://blog.brainasoft.com/all-internal-commands-of-cmd/)) you will need to call the batch file by its full name, in this case `rename.bat` because if you just type `rename` cmd will assume you want to call its internal command, which causes the somewhat cryptic "The syntax of the command is not correct." error because rename requires 2 parameters.

Comment: I realised that. And will accept this as the answer for the original error that appeared. But my problem remains unresolved. The error message after renaming the batch file to rename1.bat is "The system cannot find the file specified". The file is there and the dir command displays it.

Comment: See the comment I added to the question itself, as we seem to be leaving the domain of what's considered an on topic question for SO I suggest you re-ask the question on superuser, as it works here chances are it's more of an operational error.